# Custom PC keeps destroying components

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, desktop-computer, water-cooling

We build a custom water-cooling system with the following specs:

```
CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 3950X (16x 3,5 GHz)
Board: Gigabyte Aorus Master X570
GPU: Gigabyte Aorus GeForce RTX 2080 Ti Xtreme Waterforce WB 11G
RAM: 32GB G.Skill Trident Z RGB DDR4-3600 DIMM CL17
SSD: 2 x 1TB Crucial P1 NVMe SSD
Power: 1000 Watt Corsair HXi Series HX1000i
Case: Lian Li PC-O11DW Dynamic Midi-Tower

Fans: 5 x 120mm
Radiators: EK Water Blocks EK-CoolStream PE 360 + EK Water Blocks EK-CoolStream PE 240
Distro (Pump + Reservoir): Lian Li O11D Distro-Plate G1
```

(Full specs incl. water-cooling [here](https://pastebin.com/zEwx4YjG))

After a while the first pump of the Distro Plate died, then after an upgrade to a pump twice as strong the second one. Then the mainboard died (because of a bad power supply which got replaced) and got replaced and now the third pump which was connected to an external power brick, died as well. We think we seriously did something wrong, but we can't seem to find the reason.

Our first loop was from Distro Plate split to GPU and CPU where each went into a separate Radiator and were merged into the Distro plate after this, but as we thought it might be the reason of the pump not working anymore, we restructured into two semi-separate loops one going directly into cpu and rad 1 and after that going into gpu and rad 2.

Comment: I don't think it's your PSU that's killing things, you likely have a vacuum or a positive pressure element somewhere which is burning out the motor in the pump. https://www.ekwb.com/guides/

Comment: What you linked are handy guides and I read a couple of them, but I can't find anything about vacuum or positive pressure. I suppose that it could have something to do with a tight angle we bend in the system?

Comment: You could also have an airlock in the radiator. You might be better on a water cooling forum, or something affiliated with EK. Not sure SU is the best place for something like this... Overclockers would be a good place to start https://www.overclockers.co.uk/forums/community/watercooling.133/

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks a lot for your help, I opened a thread there now.

Comment: Link back if anyone is interested https://www.overclockers.co.uk/forums/threads/custom-water-cooled-pc-breaks-down.18899182/